# ionic display product lists based on category

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ionic-framework

I have a shopping list app I want to display the products based on the categories, I want the products to display something like this where the categories names look different

[image: result sample]

Here is my code for the products

```
var products = [{
    "id": "219",
    "product_id": "198909",
    "sku": "20148089",
    "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "45.09",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Bakery & Desserts"
}, {
    "id": "220",
    "product_id": "199403",
    "sku": "20008307",
    "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "10.99",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Carrots & Beetroot"
}, {
    "id": "221",
    "product_id": "204759",
    "sku": "6009207908908",
    "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "40.78",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Fresh Food"
 }, {
    "id": "222",
    "product_id": "199015",
    "sku": "6009182131643",
    "prod_name": "Bulk White Gouda Cheese 900g",
    "vendor": "Woolworths",
    "price": "126.45",
    "status": "0",
    "category": "Cheese"
  }];
    let categories = {};
    products.forEach(product => {
    if (!Object.keys(categories).includes(product.category)) {
            categories[product.category] = {
                    items: []
            };
    }
  });
    products.forEach(product => {
    Object.keys(categories).forEach(category => {
            if (product.category === category) {
                    categories[category].items.push(product);
            }
    });
 });
   console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories=products.map(product=>product.category)
var result=categories.map(category=>{
 return{'category':category,'products':products.filter(product=>product.category==category)}
    })
```

Comment: Code-only answers are acceptable, but they become much more useful when they include a description of what the code does, why, and how it addresses the original problem.